# Need Help Understanding Invalid Argument Error When Creating Vertex Shader

Tags: c++, directx, directx-11

I'm just starting out in DirectX 11, and I've run into a problem. I'm loading an extremely simple shader in an HSDL file:

```
struct VOut{
float4 position : SV_POSITION;
float4 color : COLOR;
};

VOut VS_Main( float4 pos : POSITION, float4 color : COLOR )
{
VOut output;

output.position = pos;
output.color = color;

return output;
}


float4 PS_Main( float4 pos : SV_POSITION, float4 color : COLOR ) : SV_TARGET
{
return color;
}
```

Using the following code (that DOES NOT trigger the if(FAILED(result) statement):

```
bool PathfindingDemoBase::CompileD3DShader(char* filePath, char* entry, char* shaderModel, ID3DBlob** buffer){
DWORD shaderFlags = D3DCOMPILE_ENABLE_STRICTNESS;

#if defined(DEBUG) || defined(_DEBUG)
shaderFlags |= D3DCOMPILE_DEBUG;
#endif

ID3DBlob* errorBuffer = 0;
HRESULT result;

result = D3DX11CompileFromFile(filePath, 0, 0, entry, shaderModel,
    0, 0, 0, buffer, &errorBuffer, 0);

if(FAILED(result)){
    if(errorBuffer != 0){
        OutputDebugStringA((char*)errorBuffer->GetBufferPointer());
        errorBuffer->Release();
    }

    return false;
}

if(errorBuffer != 0){
    errorBuffer->Release();
}

return true;
}
```

But what does happen is in the LoadContent function, the commented line (//<---) triggers an "E_INVALIDARG" result (in d3dResult), but the vsBuffer-> calls aren't returning null :/

```
bool AStarDemo::LoadContent(){
ID3D10Blob* vsBuffer = 0;
bool compileResult = CompileD3DShader("ReturnColor.hlsl", "VS_Main", "vs_5_0", &vsBuffer);

if(compileResult == false){
    MessageBox(0, "Error loading vertex shader!", "Compile Error", MB_OK);
    return false;
}

HRESULT d3dResult;

d3dResult = d3dDevice->CreateVertexShader(vsBuffer->GetBufferPointer(),
    vsBuffer->GetBufferSize(), 0, &returnColorVS);
//actually set the vertex shader
d3dContext->VSSetShader(returnColorVS, 0, 0);

if(FAILED(d3dResult)){
    if(vsBuffer){
        vsBuffer->Release();
    }

    return false;
}

D3D11_INPUT_ELEMENT_DESC solidColorLayout[] ={
    { "POSITION", 0, DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32B32_FLOAT, 0, 0, D3D11_INPUT_PER_VERTEX_DATA, 0 }
};

unsigned int totalLayoutElements = ARRAYSIZE(solidColorLayout);

d3dResult = d3dDevice->CreateInputLayout(solidColorLayout, totalLayoutElements,
    vsBuffer->GetBufferPointer(), vsBuffer->GetBufferSize(), &inputLayout);

vsBuffer->Release();

if(FAILED(d3dResult)){
    return false;
}

ID3D10Blob* psBuffer = 0;
compileResult = CompileD3DShader("ReturnColor.hlsl", "PS_Main", "ps_5_0", &psBuffer);
//actually set the pixel shader
d3dContext->PSSetShader(returnColorPS, 0, 0);

if(compileResult == false){
    MessageBox(0, "Error loading pixel shader!", "Compile Error", MB_OK);
    return false;
}

d3dResult = d3dDevice->CreatePixelShader(psBuffer->GetBufferPointer(),
    psBuffer->GetBufferSize(), 0, &returnColorPS);

psBuffer->Release();

if(FAILED(d3dResult)){
    return false;
}

Vertex vertices[4 * TOTAL_NUMBER_GRID_SQUARES];
gridSquares = new GridSquare[TOTAL_NUMBER_GRID_SQUARES];
//for each grid square
for(int i = 0; i < TOTAL_NUMBER_GRID_SQUARES; i++){

    XMFLOAT4 color = ((i%2) == 0) ? GREEN : RED;

    //create a grid square object
    GridSquare gs;
    gs.TopLeft = Vertex( XMFLOAT3(0.5f * i,  0.5f * i, Z_LEVEL),
                        color);
    gs.TopRight = Vertex( XMFLOAT3( 0.5f * i, -0.5f * i, Z_LEVEL),
                        color);
    gs.BottomRight = Vertex( XMFLOAT3(-0.5f * i, -0.5f * i, Z_LEVEL),
                        color);
    gs.BottomLeft = Vertex( XMFLOAT3(-0.5f * i,  0.5f * i, Z_LEVEL),
                        color);

    gs.type = ((i%2) == 0) ? prey : hunter;

    gridSquares[i] = gs;

    vertices[4*i] = gs.TopLeft;
    vertices[(4*i)+1] = gs.TopRight;
    vertices[(4*i)+2] = gs.BottomRight;
    vertices[(4*i)+3] = gs.BottomLeft;
}

D3D11_BUFFER_DESC vertexDesc;
ZeroMemory(&vertexDesc, sizeof(vertexDesc));
vertexDesc.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_DYNAMIC;
vertexDesc.BindFlags = D3D11_BIND_VERTEX_BUFFER;
vertexDesc.ByteWidth = 4 * TOTAL_NUMBER_GRID_SQUARES * sizeof(Vertex);
vertexDesc.CPUAccessFlags = D3D11_CPU_ACCESS_WRITE;

D3D11_SUBRESOURCE_DATA resourceData;
ZeroMemory(&resourceData, sizeof(resourceData));
resourceData.pSysMem = vertices;

d3dResult = d3dDevice->CreateBuffer(&vertexDesc, &resourceData, &vertexBuffer);

if(FAILED(d3dResult)){
    return false;
}

return true;
}
```

Any advice would be greatly appreciated! :)

Comment: One other problem noted here is that your input layout doesn't match the input layout of the shader. They should always match, or the debug layer complains and the shader (more often than not) will render things incorrectly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the answer after digging around a bit- apparently there are some problems with using "ps_5_0" and "vs_5_0", even though my machine runs DirectX 11

Comment: For clarity: change ps_5_0 to ps_4_0 (similiar for vs).